# rich:dataList pagination?

Tags: ajax, list, jsf, pagination, richfaces

I know you can use a `<rich:datascroller>` when you want pagination on a `<rich:dataTable>`.  But, what about a `<rich:dataList>` or `<rich:dataOrderedList>`?  Is there any mechanism for pagination on these components?  Or will I have to code in the logic by hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowhere it is said that [`<rich:datascroller>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_datascroller.html) works only with `<rich:dataTable>`. So I'd assume it works with most iteration tags - try it.

If it for some reason doesn't, you can easily emulate the appearance of a list using a table (with proper css)

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Even though the RichFaces docs imply that it can only be used with a data table, I found an example in the book "Practical RichFaces" that shows it being used with a data list.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It would be very easy to build your own dataScroller.
You can use the first and rows attributes on the `<rich:dataList>` component.

To accomplish this task all you have to do is write a bean that will handle the attribute values

```
<rich:dataList id="myList" first="#{dataScrollerBean.first}" rows="#{dataScrollerBean.rows}">
<a4j:commandButton action="#{dataScrollerBean.prev}" value="< Prev" reRender="myList"/>
<a4j:commandButton action="#{dataScrollerBean.next}" value="Next >" reRender="myList"/>
```